# Error: no matching function for call to QSortFilterProxyModel::setSourceModel(NavaidsModel&

Tags: c++, qt

I'm facing a compilation problem using QSortFilterProxyModel when trying to setSourceModel.

The error message is : no matching function for call to QSortFilterProxyModel::setSourceModel(NavaidsModel&)

and the candidate is : virtual void SortFilterProxyModel::setSourceModel(QAbstractItemModel*)

Here is my code :

main.cpp

```
#include "navaidsmodel.h"
#include <QListView>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>

int main(int c, char **v)
{
    QApplication a(c, v);

    //Model
    NavaidsModel model;
    model.readFromCSV(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/files/data.csv");

    //Proxy
    QSortFilterProxyModel *proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel;
    proxyModel->setSourceModel(model);                              //Here is the trick

    //Filter
    QRegExp rx("ROBU");
    rx.setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    rx.setPatternSyntax(QRegExp::Wildcard);
    proxyModel->setFilterRegExp(rx);
    proxyModel->setFilterKeyColumn(0);

    //View
    QListView view;
    view.setUniformItemSizes(true);
    view.setModel(proxyModel);
    view.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

and here is the constructor for navaidsmodel :

```
class NavaidsModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    NavaidsModel(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR):QAbstractListModel(parent){
    }
    enum NavaidsRoles {
        PositionRole = Qt::UserRole + 1, 
        OACICodeRole,
        CountryCodeRole
    };
```

So, I understand setSourceModel request a QAbstractItemModel.

For me, NavaidsModel inherit from QAbstractListModel which inherit from QAbstractItemModel.

So, it should be OK, but it isn't.

Could you explain me what is the root cause of the problem ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setSourceModel` wants a **pointer** to a model, not a value or reference. So all you have to do is change the line

```
proxyModel->setSourceModel(model);
```

to

```
proxyModel->setSourceModel(&model);
```

Alternatively, you could also create your model with new instead, i.e.

```
NavaidsModel *model = new NavaidsModel();
```

EDIT:

When working with pointers, you should always either prefer smart pointer or use the Qt parent-child mechanisms to automatically delete the models with their view. You should make your two models children of the view:

```
int main(int c, char **v)
{
    QApplication a(c, v);

    // create the view first
    QListView view;

    //Model
    NavaidsModel *model = new NavaidsModel(&view);
    model->readFromCSV(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/files/data.csv");

    //Proxy
    QSortFilterProxyModel *proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(&view);
    proxyModel->setSourceModel(model);

    // ...
```

Comment: It's really a pain for me usage between pointers and variables. Basically, I understand correctly the difference but when to the wall, I'm not able to structure my mind correctly. Same for the usage of "new". Thank you very much for your help and recommendations.

Comment: You should really try to wrap your head around that. Wrong usage of pointers can lead to some very nasty bugs. You should probably read: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html , https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsharedpointer.html and https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscopedpointer.html . These are all safe ways to handle pointers, which you should try to follow and use.